# Determine the complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Let say i have given an algorithmen `X`, which gets as an input an integer `n`.

Now consider  the X needs for  all input n which are smaller then `x`(  `x` is a fixed arbitrarily natural number)
 O(n<sup>2</sup>) steps. But for every input `n > x` it takes n steps.

**Question:** What is the (worstcase)runtime complexity of X?

**Answer:** The (worstcase) runtime complexity of X is O(n). For every fixed x, we can find numbers n such that n>(x<sup>2</sup>) and the (worst case) runtime for all n with n>(x<sup>2</sup>) is O(n). I am not sure if my answer is correct.

**Edit: for better understanding** `T(n, x) \in if n <= x then O(n^2)` else `O(n)`. What is the worstcase runtime complexity?

Comment: Are you saying that you've an algorithm X, with complexity function `T(n, x) \in if n <= x then O(n^2) else O(n)`? I think you need to clarify things a bit.

Comment: yes, thats correct. I will edit my post to add the pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime complexity of the algorithm X with the cost function (uniform cost criteria) `T(n, x)` which is a member of `O(n^2)` when `n <= x`, otherwise a member of `O(n)`, i.e: `T(n, x) \in if n <= x then O(n^2) else O(n)` is, if we fix `x \in Nat` to an arbitrary number as you say, `O(n)`.

This is the case because once `x` is fixed, and given that natural numbers have no bound, there is always a `n >= x^2`, wherefore we can disregard `O(n^2)` when dealing with the asymptotics of the algorithm.

Therefore, `R(n) = T(n, x) \in O(n)`.

I find your reasoning to be sound.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, all that matters for Big-Oh (or any complexity bound) is behavior for all values of `n` above some fixed bound. Your algorithm is eventually linear in `n` and so the runtime is bound by `O(n)`.

Note that if your algorithm accepts an input of `n`, what that actually means is that is accepting a representation of `n` in some number system. On typical computers this will be a 2-bit (binary) representation. A base-k (k-ary) representation will take log_k(n) digits, rounded up. So if you are in a binary system and the number is 9, the representation is 1001 and it takes 4 bits (log base 2 of 9 is greater than 3 but less than 2, so four bits).

Given this, your input size isn't actually `n` but `log_2(n)` (assuming binary) and if your algorithm takes time `n`, the runtime w.r.t. the input size is actually exponential (since n = 2^(log_2 n)).

This is a minor nitpick but one that might make you think about algorithms differently. The distinction disappears if instead of taking a number you take a list with `n` elements in it.